# Modifying view data in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My company uses Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and T-SQL for its database functionalities. One the daily activities my team performs is updating the data in a view that contains around 4k-5k records.

Let's suppose the view has 10 fields. So our job is to change the value of `field_5`, considering the values of `field_1`, `field_2` and `field_7`. We have always been doing it manually and it takes close to 2-3 hours to go through all 5k records and check all the fields' values and update the required field.

I thought of automating the task and build a script for it but I can't seem to find anything on MSDN. The closest I got was this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178076.aspx. But it talks about altering the structure of the view, not updating the data inside the view while retaining structure. Further googling also didn't help much.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the definition of the view? Does it meet the criteria for an updatable view? If so you just need an update statement.

A trivial example would be

```
UPDATE YourView
SET Field5 = Field1+Field2+Field7
```

Otherwise if it does not meet the requirements you could write an instead of trigger implementing the desired logic and still use an update statement.

Comment: Thanks Martin. It looks promising. I'll try with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you use the word 'View' but I assume you mean a 'Table'? Views are dynamic and (apart from indexed views) don't actually store data, they store queries that run a certain set of code when you call the view.

Assuming you're talking about a table, you're looking for something like below;

```
UPDATE table
SET field_5 = (field_1 + field_2 + field_7)
```

That will change field_5 in every row to match your calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would reach that conclusion that they must be talking about tables when the word "view" is specified five times. Data can be modified through views https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180800.aspx

Comment: Are you actually updating the data 'in a view' here though or are you updating it using a view. The wording of the OP led me to believe that there's a view with around 4-5k records which op must go through and update some values, I'm assuming, for a final report. OP also linked to an MSDN article on how to modify a view rather than 'how to update data using a view'. It may be that I've understood this incorrectly, I'm more than happy to be corrected on this. I've always considered views as a tool to retrieve data rather than modify it.

Comment: You're updating it using a view. The actual changes get written back to the base tables.

Comment: Ok, sure. I'd choose a different way of persisting that field but each to their own. Thanks for educating me on this.